# Is there currently a way to get the Stella Victory badge?

Tags: ingress

Is there any way to get this badge? [This page](https://niantic.schlarp.com/investigation:apps:ingress:badges#stella_vyctory) tells:

> These are only obtained via passcodes at Shōnin Pasadena, or by participating in the website [Endgame - Ancient Societies](http://www.ancientsocieties.com/).

Shōnin clearly is over. What about this website? What to do?

I'm an iOS user, so I can not even play *Endgame* yet.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

During anomaly last week (June 20th, 2015) in Utrecht, there was a card given with an encrypted message to decode. Agents who were able to give the right answer before midnight won Stella's badge (even without being present et anomaly event).

Sorry it's too late now. My answer if you want these kind of badges is go to anomaly events, and if not at least be in contact with people going there.